# Node.js gives unpredictable ajax response on the first time of startup

Tags: node.js, jquery, canjs

I am using node.js as back end and canjs as front end library.

Node code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var cons = require('consolidate')

app.configure(function(){
      app.engine('html', cons.handlebars);
      app.set('view engine', 'html');
      app.set('views', __dirname)
      app.use(express.favicon())
      app.use(express.logger('dev'))
      app.use(express.static(__dirname ))
      app.use(express.bodyParser())
      app.use(express.methodOverride())
      app.use(express.cookieParser("secret"))
      app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }))
      app.use(app.router)
    });

app.init = function(){
    fs.readFile('./sample.json', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            throw(error);
        }
        else
            app.set("json", data);
    })};

app.get('/things', function(req, res){
    app.init();
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/json');
    res.send(app.get("json"));
});

app.get('/things/:id', function(req, res){
    app.init();
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/json');
    res.send((JSON.parse(app.get("json")))[req.param('id')]);
});

app.get('/main.html', function(req, res){
    app.init(function(error, data){
        if (error) {throw error}
        res.render('main.html');
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Can.js code:

```
Todo = can.Model({
    findAll: "GET /things",
    findOne: "GET /things/{id}",
},{});

$(document).ready(function(){

    Todo.findAll({}, function(todos){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(todos));
    })

    Todo.findOne( { id: 1 }, function( todo ) {
        console.log( todo );
    })

});
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./can.jquery-1.0.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./can.fixture.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./master.js"></script>
```

JSON:

```
{"0":{"id":1,"name":"do the dishes"},"1":{"id":2,"name":"go to dentist"},"2":{"id":3,"name":"go swimming"},"4":{"id":5,"name":"masturbate"}}
```

Each time the server is started up, the console will find the ajax GET response for both functions (findAll and findOne) returning either undefined or 500 error:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/things". jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
undefined master.js:12

GET http://localhost:3000/things/1 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/things/1". jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type
```

But if I refresh the page after this, the two functions will work normally, giving:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/things". jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
{"0":{"id":1,"name":"do the dishes"},"1":{"id":2,"name":"go to dentist"},"2":{"id":3,"name":"go swimming"},"4":{"id":5,"name":"masturbate"},"length":0,"_namespace":".observe2"} master.js:12
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/things/1". jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
Constructor {name: "go to dentist", _data: Object, id: 2, _namespace: ".observe3"}
 master.js:16
```

What is GOING ON??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `app.get("json");` before its value has been set by the `fs.readfile` callback in `app.init` (which occurs sometime after the first call to `app.init();` returns).

You should probably change your code to only call `app.init` once, and don't listen for requests until its work completes.

```
app.init = function(callback){
    fs.readFile('./sample.json', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            throw(error);
        } else {
            app.set("json", data);
            callback();
        }
    });
};

...

app.init(function() {
    app.listen(3000);
});
```

Comment: I think it's worse than this.  It seems that the "main.html" request is never being handled.  It's probably sitting in the same directory and served by `express.static`.  So the route he thinks is initing the sample.json actually isn't happening (I don't think).  After that, the json is being reset every time, but *after* the request.  So each subsequent request is looking at the JSON loaded by the request prior.

Comment: It's possible I'm wrong on that, but if the main handler *is* intercepting the request, it's passing a callback to `init` which doesn't take one, so the code within (which renders the page) wouldn't happen.