# Synchronous answer from Q promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am writing an application in node.js.

The configuration for the application exists in a database.

I have created a general module that can talk to the database and return the  reply in Q promise.

I am now creating a specific module, which exists to get config for my app.
This is the `config` module below. The `getconfig()` function returns a Q promise. But I would like to get the reply synchronously.

In another module (see code below) I would like for that module to get the configuration in order to know how to talk to a service (aws s3 in this case).

So the first thing I would do when instantiating that module is to get the configuration.
And I would like it so that whenever that module is instantiated, it is also configured. This would need to be done synchronously.

```
var s3Module = (function () {

  var _config = config.getConfig().s3;
  var bucket = _config.bucket;
  return {
    pushToS3: function (payload, fulfilled) {
      var params = buildParams(payload);
      s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
          error(err);
        else
          fulfilled(data);
      });
    }
  };

})();
```

However using promises I can not see how I can ensure that the config is returned from the database when I begin calling the functions of the module

Comment: It's just not possible. Rethink your architecture - add an `init()` function that accepts a callback - similar to how jQuery's `$()` gets executed on dom ready.

Comment: *The getconfig() function returns a Q promise. But I would like to get the reply synchronously.* - Promises can not make an asynchronous operation synchronous.

Comment: @slebetman could you maybe elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: An intrinsically async operation that you 'make synchronous' effectively means blocking your code, which will ruin performance

Comment: @SimonH Yes I get that, but to have a module instantiated without config kinda doesn't make sense. Hence it would be worth witing for the config

Comment: @slebetman Ahh after reading your comment a bit more I get it - I think. You basically say to run the entire app in a callback, and have that callback run when config is returned. If you write an answer with a simple example code, the answer is yours...

Comment: Why are you using a promise in `getConfig()`? You don't want it to be async so remove the promise and make it sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after @slebetman comment I found an answer here:
[Node.js gives unpredictable ajax response on the first time of startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354953/node-js-gives-unpredictable-ajax-response-on-the-first-time-of-startup)

My question is basically a duplicate of the above question.